# My Procedure for checking login Credentials is given below it gives error pls give solution

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `skilltest`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE Validate_User1($Username NVARCHAR(20), $_Password NVARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
DECLARE $UserId INT;DECLARE $LastLoginDate DATETIME;
IF EXISTS(SELECT (Username) FROM Users WHERE Username=$Username)
THEN
BEGIN
IF  EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username=$Username AND _Password=$_Password)
THEN
BEGIN
SELECT -1 -- UserValidate
END$$
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT -2 -- Password Wrong
END$$
END$$
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT -3 -- USERNAME DOES NOT EXIST
END$$
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Better you provide your purpose of creating this Stored Procedure and which error is it returning? No one can understand your error by looking at this.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the welcome tour to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is mysql (there are elements in the code which suggest sql server) every statement must terminate with ; , a comment should be preceeded by # (not --), every if must have a matching end if; , begin..end blocks are not required in the if...endif blocks, only one else is allowed per if, every begin must have a matching end;
, only 1 end $$ is required. Although not required syntactically indenting your code makes it much more readable for us humans.

The following at least syntaxes

```
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Validate_User1;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE Validate_User1($Username NVARCHAR(20), $_Password NVARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
DECLARE $UserId INT;DECLARE $LastLoginDate DATE;
IF EXISTS(SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE Username=$Username) THEN
    IF  EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username=$Username AND _Password=$_Password) THEN
        SELECT -1; #UserValidate 
    ELSE
        SELECT -2; #Password Wrong
    END IF;
ELSE
        SELECT -3; #USERNAME DOES NOT EXIST
END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```